# Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket while executing docker build

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to build docker image through Jenkins installed on Ubuntu 16.04.
However, getting the error stated :

`"Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post"`.

Any suggestions are welcomed...Thanks!!!

Comment: Is the user executing Jenkins part of the docker group?

Comment: I have added the user to docker group.Still the issue remains same.

Comment: @amitsingh does it work with the root user?

Comment: @Ivthillo: Nope

Comment: Did you restart Jenkins as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44444163/6309?

Comment: Did you mount the socket as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44979356/6309?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands

1. `sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER`
2. `newgrp docker`

Then run your command :-)