# Jenkins agent on GKE failed to run docker dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm running Jenkins helm on GKE standard cluster with Container-Optimized OS with Docker (cos) image.

I'm running jenkins agent with docker installed and jenkins user added to docker group. I'm mounting /var/run/docker.sock as volume .. also tried t run with UID 1000.

```
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

But still getting dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied ?! Any idea what I'm missing here ?

Comment: Have you enabled docker ?

Comment: this might give some idea
https://estl.tech/accessing-docker-from-a-kubernetes-pod-68996709c04b

but based on your scenario i think it will not be allowed by gke security

may I know what target do you want to achieve by running docker in docker?

Comment: @again On the host you mean ? If yes, then the answer is yes as I'm using the Container-Optimized OS with Docker (cos) image.

Comment: @Yuyanto that's exactly what I figured out .. running the agent with 412 GID made it work! The scenario is to run Jenkins agents as executors to run docker commands in pipeline.

Comment: @Nurhun you might need to check kaniko
https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @again comment, below are possible reasons to look for regarding pemission denied error:

- Docker is not installed on host
- UID 1000 does not have permission to /var/run/docker.sock (try to chmod 777 the file temporarily and reduce permssion as needed)
- Check Host and Container docker ID, must have the same UID

Also, you can refer on related links below for possible answers.

[Docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854463/docker-got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socke?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Run Docker as jenkins-agent, in a docker-container, as non-root user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54452152/run-docker-as-jenkins-agent-in-a-docker-container-as-non-root-user?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Use docker inside docker with jenkins user #263](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/issues/263)

[docker.sock permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568172/docker-sock-permission-denied)

Comment: This's all working if you have control on host machines .. here, the problem is you don't have this privilege on VMs managed by google kubernetes engine GKE